# Appending 2D arrays in a final 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I have a problem appending a list of `2D arrays` in a final `2D array`.

**Problem Statement:**

If I have 2 `2D arrays`:

```
array1 = {{0,0},
          {0,1}};

array2 = {{0,1},
          {0,2}};
```

**I want the final 2D array in this form:**

```
final_array = {{0,0,0,1},
               {0,1,0,2}};
```

**And it should not be size dependent. It should work for different sizes also. Like:**

```
array1={{0,0},
        {0,0}};

array2={{0,1},
        {0,2}};

array3={{1,0},
       {1,1}};

array4={{0,3},
       {1,4}};

final_array = {{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,3},
               {0,0,0,2,1,1,1,4}};
```

I tried the following to achieve but I am not getting the desired result:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] a = {{0,0},
                      {0,0}};
    int[][] b = {{0,1},
                      {0,1}};
    String array1_str = Arrays.deepToString(a);
    String array2_str = Arrays.deepToString(b);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(append(a, b)));

  }

  public static int[][] append(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
        int[][] result = new int[a.length + b.length][];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, result, 0, a.length);
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, result, a.length, b.length);
        return result;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this kind of appending?

Comment: As always on SO: show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: updated my question @dave

Comment: @Hiren What result does your code give you right now?

Comment: I wanted all the first rows of 2D arrays should become the first row of the final 2D array and then second row of all 2D arrays should become the second row of the final 2D array. But in my solution. The first row of 2nd 2D array is becoming the second row of the final array. @Brian

Answer (score 0):

You may use 2D ArrayList and List in java.util. You can loop through the 2d-arrays, fill the list append it to the array list, and do it for the second row etc.

You may try like:

```
List<List<Integer>> finalArray = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

// loop through the first row of arrays and fill the list
// long form of loop statement 
List<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
row.add(array1_str[0][0]); 
row.add(array1_str[0][1]);
row.add(array2_str[0][0]); 
row.add(array2_str[0][1]); // ...
finalArray.add(row);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(finalArray.toArray()));
```

Comment: any generic way of solving the problem ?

Comment: @Hiren Figuring that out is the point of the homework assignment, I would think.